# Next JS Framework: syntax build static file "npm run build" run too slow

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a app which bases on NextJS Framework

Everytime I run syntax "npm run build", the app will generate static files (HTML and CSS). And put it to folder "out".

This is my app and structure: https://prnt.sc/rnlz30
This is my process: https://prnt.sc/rnlzas

But the process is really slow. It spent 4 hours for export 1815 pages. And i have no idea how to optimize process speed.

Thank you everyone.

Comment: oki Thank @iamhuynq